# Убрать свой процесс из списка полученных процессов

Tags: c#, процесс

```
var pro = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var pcc in pro)
{
     var wt = pcc.MainWindowTitle;
     if (pcc.MainWindowTitle == string.Empty) 
     { 
        wt = "- N/A"; 
     }
     Console.WriteLine($"Процесс: {pcc.ProcessName}");
}
```

Получаю список всех процессов, но и так же получаю имя своего процесса, как его обойти?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получите текущий процесс через `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` и сравните Id процесса с Id текущего процесса:

```
var pro = Process.GetProcesses();
var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (var pcc in pro)
{
    if (currentProcess.Id == pcc.Id)
        continue;

    var wt = pcc.MainWindowTitle;
    if (pcc.MainWindowTitle == string.Empty)
    {
        wt = "- N/A";
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Процесс: {pcc.ProcessName}");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо), А можно так же убрать пустой процесс `Idle.exe` ?

Comment: @ArteS Разумеется. Idle -- это процесс с PID = 0, перепишите условие так: ```if (currentProcess.Id == pcc.Id || pcc.Id == 0)```